# Datatable is not showing after using django pagination

Tags: python, django, templates, pagination

I am having problem with pagination in django. After using pagination,not even able to show table in the template.Please find below views.py and template.I mark the problem area. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paginator=Paginator('test',10)# show 10 results per page
```

here you pass a 'test' string to Paginator, instead pass test object so it will be

```
paginator=Paginator(test,10)# show 10 results per page
```

hope it will work